# Testing in Scala

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am new to Scala and mostly to JVM in general.

There is a statement in the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EX49FOU):

> To provide descriptive error messages when assertions fail, ScalaTest
>   analyses the expressions passed to each assert invocation **at compile
>   time**.

which confused me a lot.

What does this actually mean? How can `ScalaTest` access compile time information?

Answer (score 2):

ScalaTest uses [macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) for this purpose. Using macros they are able to analyse the expression passed into the assert. ScalaTest does not use standard Scala `assert` in the [Predef package](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/Predef$.html), they provide their own implementation of the `assert` - you can read more about it at [ScalaTest Using assertions](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions).

Comment: So It is similar to .NET [expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) or F#'s [Code Quotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/code-quotations)

Comment: I do not think they are that similar - they both seem to provide a representation of expressions, which is used run time. Macros also receive the expression representation, but difference is then run compile time (by the compiler, when compiling the source code).

Answer (score 2):

Scala supports [macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) to enable this kind of features. Scala macro can analyze the syntax tree at the call site and extract useful information from it. Libraries like ScalaTest use macros to obtain information about call site to provide e.g. error messages based on variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Consider next few examples(I use ScalaTest features like `Matchers` and `GivenWhenThen`):

First one is about objects equality testing.

```
"ScalaTest" should "provide descriptive error messages when checking objects equality" in{
    Given("two different List objects")
    val list1 = List("I", "am", "the", "list")
    val list2 = Seq("No", "I", "am", "the", "list")
    When("we try to check them for equality with ScalaTest tools")
    Then("we can see what exactly differs")
    list1 should equal(list2)
  }
```

Please notice that object types differ in values declaration.
When you run it you will see `List("I", "am", "the", "list") did not equal List("No", "I", "am", "the", "list")` in the output.
So ScalaTest is flexible enough to tell you that two lists differs and you see it in the error message.

Next example shows you values comparison:

```
"ScalaTest" should "provide descriptive error messages when comparing values with natural ordering" in{
    Given("two different numbers")
    val value1 = 40l
    val value2 = 50l
    When("we try to compare them for equality with ScalaTest tools")
    Then("we ScalaTest failure message should clearly state what happened")
    value1 should be > value2
  }
```

Running it you will get this output:`40 was not greater than 50`.
This is maximally descriptive as it can be for such test.
As you see, `value1 should be > value2` assertion is nicely analyzed to provide us with the `40 was not greater than 50` failure message.

Now let's consider standard `assert` method from `Predef.scala`:

```
"Predef.assert()" should "not provide descriptive enough error messages" in{
    Given("two different List objects")
    val list1 = List("I", "am", "the", "list")
    val list2 = Seq("No", "I", "am", "the", "list")
    When("we try to check them for equality with Predef.scala asserts")
    Then("we only get an exception with compile-time provided message")
    Predef.assert(list1 == list2, "Lists are not equal")
    succeed
  }
```

It outputs `assertion failed: Lists are not equal`. This is less descriptive than with ScalaTest.

As already stated in the answers above macros is used to implement such behavior. Declaration of the ScalaTest `assert` method in the `Assertions.scala` is following:

`def assert(condition: Boolean)(implicit prettifier: Prettifier, pos: source.Position): Assertion = macro AssertionsMacro.assert`